# Can i use sharepoint Online without Office365 online

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, subscriptions

A friend of my gave me an invite to Office365 which i now have installed in on my home PC.

Now i need to use MsAccess to export a DB to a sharepoint online however i dont have sharepoint yet. Which flavour do i need so i can export stuff from Access on my PC to a sharepoint site.

I see i can get a subscription to just sharepoint (without any O365 apps; would this Plan be ok or do i have to have office online in order to use Sharepoint Online?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**As a short answer:** No you can't.

To use `SharePoint Online`, you must have a subscription on one of the following Office 365 business plans:

- Office 365 Business Essentials.
- Office 365 Business Premium.
- Office 365 Enterprise E1 (8$ per user/month).
- Office 365 Enterprise E3 (20$ per user/month).
- Office 365 Enterprise E5 (35$ per user/month).
- Office 365 Enterprise F1.

For more details check [Office 365 Plan Options](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office-365-plan-options.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Mohamed, just the info i needed and the link, i've been itching to create the basic $5 Plan1 from the Sharepoint site - good job i got your info first. Ill go with one of the Enterprise plans now. I cant upvote you yet since i haven't got enough kudos yet but cheers mate.

Comment: You are welcome, glad to hear it helped you :)